# Different behavior of the Klein-Gordon equation

Tags: harmonic-analysis, quantum-mechanics

By Fourier transform, it is well known that the Klein-Gordon, wave and Schrödinger flows are $e^{it\sqrt{1-\Delta}}$, $e^{it \sqrt{-\Delta}}$ and $e^{it\Delta}$, respectively.

I saw a phrase "the Klein-Gordon flow behaves like the wave flow at high frequency and the Schrödinger flow at low frequency."

I guess it is true at high frequency because its Fourier transform, $e^{it\sqrt{1+|\xi|^2}}$ and $e^{it|\xi|}$ are similar when $|\xi|$ is large (so we can ignore $1$). But, at low frequency, $|\xi|^2$ and $\sqrt{1+|\xi|^2}$ approach to $0$ and $1$, respectively ($e^{it|\xi|^2}$ and $e^{it\sqrt{1+|\xi|}}$).

Hence I can't understand why it behaves like Schrödinger flow.

Could you explain exactly what it means?